# yum check output reveals many missing System libraries that are actually on the system

Tags: centos, yum

I am running CentOS 6.10 and I ran `yum check` and it revealed a bunch of missing system dependencies, below is a short snippet of all of them.  There's a total of 140 lines.

```
[root@mybox /]# yum check
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, security
GConf2-2.28.0-7.el6.x86_64 has missing requires of libORBit-2.so.0()(64bit)
abrt-addon-ccpp-2.0.8-44.el6.centos.x86_64 has missing requires of abrt = ('0', '2.0.8', '44.el6.centos')
abrt-addon-ccpp-2.0.8-44.el6.centos.x86_64 has missing requires of abrt-libs = ('0', '2.0.8', '44.el6.centos')
abrt-addon-ccpp-2.0.8-44.el6.centos.x86_64 has missing requires of elfutils
abrt-addon-ccpp-2.0.8-44.el6.centos.x86_64 has missing requires of elfutils-libs
abrt-addon-ccpp-2.0.8-44.el6.centos.x86_64 has missing requires of libabrt.so.0()(64bit)
abrt-addon-ccpp-2.0.8-44.el6.centos.x86_64 has missing requires of libreport.so.0()(64bit)
abrt-addon-ccpp-2.0.8-44.el6.centos.x86_64 has missing requires of libsatyr.so.3()(64bit)
abrt-tui-2.0.8-44.el6.centos.x86_64 has missing requires of abrt-libs = ('0', '2.0.8', '44.el6.centos')
abrt-tui-2.0.8-44.el6.centos.x86_64 has missing requires of libabrt.so.0()(64bit)
abrt-tui-2.0.8-44.el6.centos.x86_64 has missing requires of libreport.so.0()(64bit)
abrt-tui-2.0.8-44.el6.centos.x86_64 has missing requires of libsatyr.so.3()(64bit)
abrt-tui-2.0.8-44.el6.centos.x86_64 has missing requires of usermode
apr-util-1.3.9-3.el6_0.1.x86_64 has missing requires of libapr-1.so.0()(64bit)
```

running ldconfig shows these libraries being linked.

```
[root@mybox /]# ldconfig -v | grep libabrt.so
        libabrt.so.0 -> libabrt.so.0.0.1
```

I am not sure what else to look at at this point.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I found [this related question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/90491/why-does-yum-continue-to-complain-about-a-missing-dependency-that-is-already-ins?rq=1) very Helpful.  After running locate on the first missing library,

```
[root@myBox /]# locate libORBit-2
/usr/lib64/libORBit-2.so.0
/usr/lib64/libORBit-2.so.0.1.0
```

and then running `rpm -qf` on the library.

```
[root@myBox /]# rpm -qf /usr/lib64/libORBit-2.so.0.1.0 
file /usr/lib64/libORBit-2.so.0.1.0 is not owned by any package
```

This tells me that rpm does not actually know about this library even though it exists.  Digging deeper, we can see that yum doesn't have a package installed that even provides this library.  A package exists according to `yum whatprovides`, but it's not installed.  `yum list installed | grep ORBit2` comes up empty!

```
[root@myBox /]# yum whatprovides /usr/lib64/libORBit-2.so.0
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, security
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirror.cogentco.com
 * extras: mirrors.umflint.edu
 * updates: linux.cc.lehigh.edu
ORBit2-2.14.17-7.el6.x86_64 : A high-performance CORBA Object Request Broker
Repo        : base
Matched from:
Filename    : /usr/lib64/libORBit-2.so.0
```

So after yum installing ORBit2, this library no longer appears unlinked on the yum check results.  I just have to repeat this process for the dozens of other packages that are messed up too.